# How to input radio button value when name attribute echo from dynamic php?

Tags: php, html

how to get variables from name="pilihan[]". I will use that variable for post method

```
<?php 

$pilihan_query = "select * from pilihan where kuesioner_id='$kuesioner_id' AND no_pertanyaan='$no_pertanyaan'";
$pilihan_run = mysqli_query($con,$pilihan_query);

                            while($row_pilihan=mysqli_fetch_assoc($pilihan_run)): 
     $id = $row_pilihan['id'];
     $k_id = $row_pilihan['kuesioner_id'];
     $no_pert = $row_pilihan['no_pertanyaan'];
     $pil_jwb = $row_pilihan['pilihan_jawaban'];

?>

<li style="list-style: none;">
<input name="pilihan<?php echo $no_pert; ?>[]" type="radio" value="<?php echo $pil_jwb; ?>" style="margin-left: 21em;"> <?php echo $pil_jwb; ?>
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I make my code is `name="pilihan[]"` after submit i can get a array `pilihan` then to handle with my code to continue.

Comment: I need the name attribute to be dynamic, because I will display many questions with answers using the radio button

Comment: Sure. You can display by a loop then name become is `name="pilihan[$key_question][]"` each question have a key or id.

Comment: then how do you insert the data into the database?, sorry im newbie

Comment: @GiliadityaLinggarjati You can get the input data inside of a loop